# Change active state of item list on clicking previous and next buttons using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of items in my html which is rendered via hardcoded json data from the `itemController`. There are two buttons i.e., Previous and Next.

Initially, when the page is loaded the active state i.e., blue highlighted box is marked at `item1`. Thats fine as its one of the 1st need.

The 2nd need is that as I click Next button the active state should jump from `item1` to `item2` and so on till the active state reaches the end of the list i.e, `item5`, after further Next button clicks and Next button should be disabled till active state reaches `item5`.

Similarly, as I click Previous button the active state should jump from item5 to item4 and so on till the active state reaches top of the list i.e, item1,  after further Previous button clicks and Previous button should be disabled till active state reaches item1 and Next button enabled.

I am not able to solve this 2nd need since long time.

[Link to my plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LO55GOZx1oMQOMDpMU9o?p=preview)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I formatted your question which will be easy to read and understand your issue. Also, I removed noise from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change index of the `$scope.selectActive` in your functions `previousItem` and `nextItem` not to set them new object of last index something like this

```
  $scope.previousItem=function()
  {
    var total=$scope.items.length
    if ($scope.selectActive >0) {
      $scope.selectActive--;
    }

  }

  $scope.nextItem=function()
  {
    var total = $scope.items.length - 1;
    if ($scope.selectActive < total) {
       $scope.selectActive++;
    }

  }
```

You can check it here http://plnkr.co/edit/03N6Q1ekq5AEkCzvQGgj?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Alex... It worked... I thought that I need to loop over the items but which was not the case..good learning and understanding for me

Comment: I'm glad to help. What is the question?

Comment: one more question: how to disable the Next button when the active state reaches end of the list i.e.,from item1 to item5. Similarly, how to disable the Previous button when the active state reaches top of the list i.e., item5 to item1.

Comment: You need to modify ng-click to add logical expression to it, and to add ng-class to show disabled class if it is disabled: look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/5GhczjSYfVlQB7eThTPI?p=preview

Comment: no problem, anytime, you can mark this as answer :)